# sql, strategies to find out string contains certain texts

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I want to select any data that contains 800, 805, 888... (there are 8 pattern texts) in the column.

Do I have to use like statement 8 times for each one or is there a faster way?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM caller, 

WHERE id LIKE '%805%' OR id LIKE'%800' OR ... ;
```

(PS. I am not allowed to create another table, just using sql queries.)

Comment: what about temp table? can you create it ? or variable table?

Comment: Additionally to the answers provided, to make the query faster use [special extension and index kind](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html#AEN174603)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` is for strings, not for numbers. Assuming `id` is actually a number, you first need to cast it to a string in order to be able to apply a `LIKE` condition on it.

But once you do that, you can use an array for that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM caller 
WHERE id::text LIKE ANY (array['%805%', '%800', '81%']);
```

Comment: Thank you! id in this case is a varchar type data

Answer (score 1):

Use `any()` with an array of searched items:

```
with test(id, col) as (
values
    (1, 'x800'),
    (2, 'x855'),
    (3, 'x900'),
    (4, 'x920')
    )
select *
from test
where col like any(array['%800', '%855'])

 id | col  
----+------
  1 | x800
  2 | x855
(2 rows)
```

This is shorter to write but not faster to execute I think.